# CSS dropdown menu repaint

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, safari, repaint

This problem has been driving me nuts for a while now, and I can't find any mention of a similar problem anywhere... On FF and IE, I don't see any problems - but on Chrome and Safari, for some child and grandchild menus, the areas covered by those menus are not repainted properly when the mouse leaves those menus.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/xm23e/6/

Obligatory code snippet (sorry, but you really need to go to jsfiddle to see the whole menu - I don't see a way around that...):

`Foster Youth Scholars`

Thanks in advance!

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all to do with this line:

```css
#header-wrapper div.main-navigation ul.menu li:hover{position:static}
```

Changing `position:static` to `position:relative` will prevent that from happening.

```css
#header-wrapper div.main-navigation ul.menu li:hover { 
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xm23e/7/)

Comment: it was @3dgoo who helped, all credits go to him/her - I've just formatted the answer :)

Comment: Haha. It was a team effort @ZoltanToth. Cheers. :)

Comment: Wow - I totally missed that - sorry, @3dgoo!  Many thanks to both of you :-)